# Reformat an object

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
{
  "SOL": {
    "B": [
        "ABC",
        "DEF"
    ],
    "C": [
        "JKL",
        "MNO"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like it to read:

```
{
  "SOL": [
    {
      "id": "B",
      "states": [
      {
        "id": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "id": "DEF"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "C",
      "states": [
      {
        "id": "JKL"
      },
      {
        "id": "MNO"
      }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've managed to give an "id" key to the 2nd level but I can't figure out how to add one to each of the states - how can I do that?

Code:

```
object.SOL = Object.keys(object.SOL).map(function (k) {
    return { id: k, states: object.SOL[k] };
})
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouybL99u/)

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ouybL99u/1/) what you want? You'll need another `map` over the nested arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use another `map` inside to remap the `states` to objects:

```
object.SOL = Object.keys(object.SOL).map(function (k) {
    return { 
        id: k, 
        states: object.SOL[k].map(function(i){
            return {id: i };
        })
    }
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ouybL99u/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
object.SOL = Object.keys(object.SOL).map(function (k) {
    return { id: k, states: object.SOL[k].map(function(kk){ return {id:kk} }) };
})
```